# mysql.connector has no attribute

Tags: python, mysql, attributes, mysql-python

I have this code who is supposed to be a start to my class project, but every time I try to execute it, it says:

> AttributeError: module 'mysql.connector' has no attribute
> 'cursor_cext'.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection

def create_db(name: str) -> mysql.connector.cursor_cext.CMySQLCursor():
    """Esta função criar uma base de dados com o nome name"""
    # PASSO 1: Criar uma conexão
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="123456",
    )

    # PASSO 2: Criar uma Base de Dados
    c = mydb.cursor()
    c.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {name}")
    print(type(c))
    return c


def check_dbases() -> tuple:
    """Esta função verifica as bases de dados existentes"""
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="123456",
    )

    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
    return [x for x in cursor]
```

Comment: you can delete this and it will run `-> mysql.connector.cursor_cext.CMySQLCursor()`.

Answer (score 1):

basically, In Python, you can use type hints to specify the expected types of function arguments and return values. Type hints are specified using the : character, followed by the type and the `->` for the function.

So it would look like this:

```py
def function_name(parameter: type) -> return_type:
    # function body
```

your equivalent of the above `return_type` is invalid.

The code in the question has used: `mysql.connector.cursor_cext.CMySQLCursor()`
whereas is should either be blank (use python default) or use this `mysql.connector`.

And this is the reason for the error.

so the first method should look like this:

```py
def create_db(name: str)-> mysql.connector:
    """Esta função criar uma base de dados com o nome name"""
    # PASSO 1: Criar uma conexão
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="123456",
    )

    # PASSO 2: Criar uma Base de Dados
    c = mydb.cursor()
    c.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {name}")
    print(type(c))
    return c
```

Here is a link to the docs for type hinting:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html